# Building angular code with maven taking too much time

Tags: angular, maven, npm

Im using maven to build my angular app and deploy in tomcat. In the `pom.xml` I have mentioned the below code

```
                   <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                </execution>
```

This is working fine and the application is working fine.

The issue is, when ever I build the code, it install node and rpm and all the packages which will take a long time for the build process to complete. Is there any solution for this.